# Check SSL version of JDBC connection url

Tags: ssl, jdbc, h2db

I am using H2 DB. Following is JDBC url

`jdbc:h2:ssl://10.11.198.12:28001/opt/data/h2-Test/config-h2;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE`

How can I check which version of TLS/SSL is being used by this connection?

Comment: That doesn't follow from the URL, it is a result of the Java version used and the agreement made between the client and the server during the SSL/TLS handshake.

Comment: Take a look at [Determine SSL/TLS version using Wireshark](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/142939/determine-ssl-tls-version-using-wireshark). Wireshark works on all platforms, but if you are only using Windows you could also look at [Microsoft Message Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/message-analyzer/microsoft-message-analyzer-operating-guide).

Comment: Thank you so much @MarkRotteveel

Comment: Thank you @skomisa I will just look in to that